# Using external libraries in Eclipse plugin

Tags: jar, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

**Problem:** 
I'm making eclipse plugin and need to use external jars. 
 
**What I did:**
I maked folder lib where I added all needed jar and added them to the build path, but it's probably not enought, I found that I have to added them somehow to the plugin project dependencies, but **I couldn't find how to add them in Eclipse.** 
I use Eclipse 4.3.1 Kepler.


So I need use in my plugin something like foo.jar in which is fooClass.class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `plugin.xml` editor and select the `Runtime` tab. Add the jars to the `Classpath` section (bottom right).

This will add the jars to the `Bundle-ClassPath` entry in the MANIFEST.MF and will update the `build.properties` file to ensure the jars are included in the plugin.

Comment: Realy important thing is also that if you have more jars in some folder, that you can't add just the folder for example lib to the class path, but you have to add directly the jars from that folder, cause Eclipse is too silly for understand it. But now it works fine. Thank you.